# Instagram API Show Users Profile on my page

Tags: instagram

I am allowed to show the User Profiles on my Page with a Webcrawler? Is that legal?

I heard from Instagram Basic API, but I think I only can show my profile and not from others? Is That truth?

Answer (score 0):

don't know about the first two question but i have the answer of the last two right now you can only see those accounts who are creator or business accounts but for that you have to get auth token from you account you can also search for only business or creator account only.

Comment: i would show profiles of other users on my site. I don't want to display my profile on the site. I want to let other people view the profile